# Wordpress with Shopp plugin using a lot of resources

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shopp

I have a Wordpress install with the Shopp plugin installed for eCommerce. I have about 70 products which are all digital download based.

My site is using roughly 105MB of memory to produce the pages. This seems very high to me. I do have a couple other plugins running, but these are not causing any significant memory usage, as I have checked them.

Does this seem normal/feasible based on the WP/Shopp setup? Or does this seem high in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is quite normal with wordpress + plugins. I've seen much worse. You can try to disable some plugins to see what uses the most memory. If you make sure the max_memory is set higher than your usage (with a margin to catch the spikes) there wont be any problems.

You can also cache your website, so users that are not logged-in will see a static cache of your website, thus using no memory at all. This is a nice plugin for caching: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/ (read the manual for setup)

Comment: Thanks! I am using the WP Super Cache plugin already, just wanted to make sure this was normal.

Comment: Be sure to exclude the Shopp pages from caching though. A manual can be found here https://shopplugin.net/kb/set-up-shopp-with-wp-super-cache/